# Plugin not working in Wordpress installed via Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am beginner in docker and have setup wordpress in Docker. Everything was working fine except some plugin not working well as they should be. In my understanding, docker needs some volume mounted to work but i can't find any location of where they might be. For eg. it says "**Wordpress copying /var/ww/html** but there is actually nothing.  The main problem was when i wanted to convert wordpress into Static site but the plugin **simply static** cant't generate the files in localhost.

> I am running docker Server Version: 17.09.0-ce in Ubuntu 17.04 and
>   here is my docker-compose configuration.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  volumes:
    - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
  ports:
    - 8080:80
wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
```

Comment: Hi, I could do several wild guesses like for example: the user that owns the files in the docker host is different from the one that runs the wp process in the container, therefore wp container can't access to `uploads.ini` file. I think a log could help here :)

Comment: Would ```chown ``` help but I think the issue is just more than that here.

Comment: You're right, it could be more than I suggested. But any other SO user could help you more with the logs of the wordpress container (IIRC `docker-compose logs wordpress` should do the trick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install  `php-zip`  and the plugin will actually start to work.